# What is the threshold in AUC (Area under curve)

Tags: classification, roc, auc

Assume a binary classifier (say a random forest) `rfc` and I want to calculate the AUC. I struggle to understand how the threshold are being used in the calculation. I understand that you make a plot of TPR/FPR for different thresholds. I also understand the threshold is used as a threshold for predicting class 1 (else class 0), but how does the AUC algorithm predict classes?

Say using `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score` you pass `y_true` and `y_rfc` (being the true value and the predicted value), but I do not see how the thresholds come into play in the AUC score/plot.

I have read different guides/tutorials for AUC, but all of their explanation regarding the threshold and how it is used is kinda vague.

I have also had a look at [How does sklearn actually calculate AUROC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014078/how-does-sklearn-actually-calculate-auroc) .

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/understanding-roc-curve

Answer (score 0):

AUC curve is generated based on TPR/FPR of different thresholds. The main point of ROC is to sample threshold from (0;1) and get a point for curve. Notice that if your classifier is perfect you will get point (0,1) and for all smaller threshold cant be worst, so it also will be on (0,1) which leads to auc = 1.

AUC provide your information not only about classification quality but also about how good confidence of your classifier was evaluated.

Comment: I totally get that but how is the curve generated? And again how is the threshold used for computing the curve?

Comment: if you have threshold you can evaluate TPR/FPR which is a point on curve. Usually fragments of curve between sampled points are extrapolated by line segments https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4356897/figure/Fig1/ Threshold is  a randomly sampled value from (0; 1), usually instead of sampling implementation get all values from your model output as threshold which provide the same results.

Comment: So the threshold for "n" classes is how many of them are used for computing the TPR/FPR (ranging from [1,n]) or..?

Comment: You can use AUC only for binary classification, so you can consider only two classes "positive" and "negative". TPR and FPR are always from [0;1]. Lowering threshold encourages your classifier to answer "positive" which leads to equal or better TPR but also equal or higher FPR value. If your model is good lowering threshold should tend to increase TPR much faster than FPR.

Comment: The link you posted, they use 5 thresholds - how are they chosen? Is the threshold a proportion of the data? What is the threshold, and how do they compute the TPR/FPR according to each threshold, when using (e.g the link or the Iris data set)

Comment: You can't use directly AUC for common classification based on Iris data, because it is not a binary classifiation. After getting any threshold from (0; 1) u can get your classes for problem as list: i.e thr = 0.4, outputs = [0.52, 0.45, 0.1 ... ] -> ['positive', 'positive', 'negative' ...] This labeled sequence is used to evaluate TPR/FPR. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity formulas are on wiki on right-side table. This should be done many times for different thresholds to get points of ROC.

Comment: I dont get how the threshold can be related to an outcome of a classifier - what we use for computing is the true and predicted value.  Using only `ytrue` and `ypred`, how is the TPR/FPR point for the AUC  calculated with a specific threshold `thr`? Also why is the threshold between (0,1) - the link you posted it is {1,2,3,4,5}?

Comment: ypred should be a sequence of probability of positive class occurrence, not exactly label of this class.

Comment: In that case you can only use ROC when you have a logistic function, which I would find very odd.
Also, looking at sklearns documentation you can use the labels

Comment: none the less - say we have probabilities: how is the point calculated as a function of a threshold?

Comment: You can't evaluate AUC without sequence of probabilities.

Comment: I can suggest you to read https://medium.com/greyatom/lets-learn-about-auc-roc-curve-4a94b4d88152

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Just at short question: when using `predict_proba(X)` we get (N,2) with `[P(0),P(1)]` where `P(0)` is the probabillity of belonging to the class "0". Do we always provide the probability for a hit (thus P(1)) as `ypred`?

Comment: probability is always a term of positive class occurrence. Check your library documentation for details.